# yii framework calling controller method from extension php file

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I want to call controller method from yii extension in specific condition to trigger partial render

```
<?php
require_once (Yii::app ()->basePath . '/controllers/SiteController.php';
$obj = new SiteController();
$obj->actionGetscore();
print_r($obj);
.....
.....
?>
```

Comment: this is not the correct way of calling controller actions

Comment: Create some model with `getScore` method and use it in both controller and your extension.

Comment: i get error 404 unable to resolve the request

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::app()->controller->actionGetscore();` ?
`Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial();` ?
`Yii::app()->controller->forward('site/getscore');` ?
Controller should not have business logic, they need only for request->response.
You need to use models or same classes and there you can use:
`Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('/site/getscore', array('data'=>$data));`